# Ways to identify a remote SSH servers Key Length

Tags: command-line, ssh, key

I am new to this SSH and Bash, I am trying to know a remote SSH servers configuration for debugging purposes for e.g. to know what ciphers, MAC's, Algorithms, and length of the key that is been used by a remote server without logging in just by establishing the connection through  my bash script using

```
ssh -vvv <remote server>
```

with this command i am able to get details on ciphers, MACs, Key exchange algorithms but i am unable to find the length of the key, so similarly with a command i would like to find the length of the key without logging in to the remote server, if some one could walk me down this would be really helpful. Looking forwards, Thanks in advance

Comment: which key do you mean? There is server's host key, your authentication key for public authentication and finally the key used for key exchange.

Comment: Server's host key length (serverkeybits)

Answer (score 1):

The size of the key can be obtained using `ssh-keygen` utility. There is switch `-l`:

On your local machine you can get the length of your identity key:

```
ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

On remote machine you can get the length of server key using:

```
ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
```

or you can change the `rsa` for the key type you are using.

Comment: Thanks, but there is a problem, that is, my script will be integrated as a part of some monitoring tool and so each and every time i cant change the path to the host rsa key in my script. 

So only, i wonder whether there is a command that i can use in my script which will fetch the host key length, not just for one particular host (known host), because i am interested in multiple hosts (random or unknown host). 

e.g. say i want my script to connect to a random host server (which i already did) and i want to know the host key length (Severkeybits), without looking for some files or anything.

Answer (score 1):

NMAP will provide this functionality

`nmap <remote server> --script ssh-hostkey --script-args ssh_hostkey=all`

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but I had trouble finding a good solution and the top answer didn't work for me.  I was able to come up with a solution using a combination of ssh-keyscan and ssh-keygen (replace the hostname and rsa with the correct signature algorithm if needed ):

`ssh-keyscan -t rsa remote.hostname.com | ssh-keygen -lf -`

Should produce output that starts with:

`2048 SHA256:`

In my example the key length is 2048.